# Why is LogRocket recording a session every time I run a new Gatsby JS build

Tags: node.js, gatsby, netlify, logrocket

I'm trying to install LogRocket in my Gatsby JS app, that I am hosting on Netlify.

I only want to record sessions in production, and for the most part everything works great but I have noticed that when I push a new build to Netlify, LogRocket will always register a new session during the build process.

Is there a way to prevent LogRocket from registering a new session during the Gatsby / Netlify build process?

I'm currently initializing the session in the `onClientEntry` build hook in `gatsby-browser.js` like this:

```
exports.onClientEntry = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    LogRocket.init('<project_id>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`onInitialClientRender`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onInitialClientRender) API:

```
exports.onInitialClientRender = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    LogRocket.init('<project_id>');
  }
}
```

From the docs:

> `onInitialClientRender` `{ Function }`
>
> Called when the initial (but not subsequent) render of Gatsby App is done on the client.

Comment: It worked! The Gatsby documentation for `onInitialClientRender` is a little vague but that seems to be the right browser API to initialize this in